# check for IS NOT NULL is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem: when I execute the SQL statement

```
-- CTE
WITH My_CTE AS
(
    SELECT [table_a].[ID]
          ,[view_b].[val]
    FROM [table_a]
    LEFT JOIN [view_b] ON [a].[ID] = [b].[fk]
)
-- query with "is not null"
SELECT * FROM My_CTE WHERE val IS NOT NULL
```

the execution takes 8 seconds. In this case, this is very slow (without the NULL-check, the query returns 461 rows, and with the NULL-check, the query returns 414 rows, which is not that much).

I tried to improve speed by using a table variable:

```
-- declare table variable
DECLARE @test1 TABLE (ID int not null, val int null);

-- CTE
WITH My_CTE AS
(
    SELECT [table_a].[ID]
          ,[view_b].[val]
    FROM [table_a]
    LEFT JOIN [view_b] ON [a].[ID] = [b].[fk]
)
-- Fill table variable
INSERT INTO @test1 SELECT * FROM My_CTE

-- query with "is not null"
SELECT * FROM @test1 WHERE val IS NOT NULL
```

Here the execution finishes in less than 1 second - which is the expected behavior.

But the problem is that I cannot use table variables in views – and the above SQL statement should later be integrated into a view.

My questions are:

- What is the reason for the original code being so slow?
- Is there any method for improving speed without using table variables?

Comment: When asking for performance tuning help, you should include the execution plans for both queries. Table structures would also be very useful. Also, table sizes

Comment: Hi, can u plz move the WHERE clause to inside the CTE, and check the execution time (without table_variable)?

Comment: You do not need to LEFT JOIN when you want "not null", simply do an INNER JOIN and let it handle that for you.

Comment: @Tom H: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with execution plans. Maybe using/modifying them is indeed the solution. Can you point me to some information concerning execution plans?

Comment: I always find Brent Ozar's videos informative https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKghrpVSbc0

Comment: How does good old-fashioned `SELECT [table_a].[ID] ,[view_b].[val] FROM [table_a] a INNER JOIN [view_b] b ON [a].[ID] = [b].[fk] AND [b].val IS NOT NULL` perform?

Comment: Do you need the CTE? Is the column indexed?
 I don't have enough information, but try inlining the CTE as it may be creating a lazy spool due to either a scan operation with a bad query plan or a good deal of fragmentation causing the index to be ignored.
Either way a query plan would help.

Comment: Be careful with table variables because by default they have no statistics. Even with the flag on it isn't full blown. Only use them when you absolutely have to.

Comment: @Xaver An execution plan is the set of steps that SQL Server is planning to follow (or did follow) to get the data that you're requesting. In SQL Server Management Studion you can see them by clicking on the 3 boxes connected by arrows in the tool bar (or <ctrl>-m) and then running your query. You can also see the *expected* execution plan by using <ctrl>-L without running your query. Please Google for more information, including how to get a text version as part of your query results.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I solved my problem: Neither the LEFT JOIN (instead of an INNER JOIN) not the CTE lead to the problem. In fact, my original code (which I didn't post here) used INNER JOIN and didn't contain a CTE, but then I introduced them to my code in hope they help solve the problem. But: The problem was simply that the column was not indexed. So thanks for this hint! Also, the hint with the execution plan helped me to better understand the internals of SQL servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you stuck with using that CTE?

```
SELECT [table_a].[ID], [view_b].[val]
  FROM [table_a]
  JOIN [view_b] 
         ON [view_b].[fk] = [table_a].[ID] 
        AND [view_b].[val] IS NOT NULL
```

an index on [view_b].[val] would probably help

Comment: No, the CTE was not the problem. In fact, the problem occured before I introduced the CTE to my code. And then I was hoping that the CTE would solve the problem. However, your remark with adding an index was really good; it solved my problem. That's why I accepted your answer. (Unfortunately, using an index has the drawback of having to use the "with schemabinding" option when creating the view...but after some research I now understand why this is necessary.)